# Java only uses Default Constructor won't calculate by entered parameters

Tags: java, parameters, default-constructor

I've looked over the code a few times and I'm not sure what is affecting this and forcing it to only use the default constructor. For example if I try to put in 2000 for the amount invested it will still default to 1000.

```
public class Investment {
    private double moneyInvested;
    private double yearsInvested;

    public final static double AMOUNT_DEFAULT = 1000;
    public final static double YEARS_DEFAULT = 5;

    public final static double RATE = 0.12;

    public Investment() {
        moneyInvested = AMOUNT_DEFAULT;
        yearsInvested = YEARS_DEFAULT;
    }

    public Investment(double AMOUNT_DEFAULT, double YEARS_DEFAULT) {
        if (moneyInvested <= 0) {
            moneyInvested = AMOUNT_DEFAULT;
        }

        if (yearsInvested <= 0) {
            yearsInvested = YEARS_DEFAULT;
        }
    }

    public double getMoneyInvested() {
        return moneyInvested;
    }

    public double getYearsInvested() {
        return yearsInvested;
    }

    public void setMoneyInvested(double inputMoney) {
        moneyInvested = inputMoney;

        if (inputMoney <= 0) {
            inputMoney = 1000;
        }
    }

    public void setYearsInvested(double inputYears) {
        yearsInvested = inputYears;

        if (inputYears <= 0) {
            inputYears = 1;
        }
    }

    public static String returnValue(double inputYears, double inputMoney) {
        double returnInvestment;
        int initYears = 1;
        String returnValue = "";

        while (initYears <= inputYears) {
            returnInvestment = Math.pow(1.12, initYears) * inputMoney;
            int investReturn = (int) returnInvestment;

            returnValue = "The amount at end of year " + initYears + " is "
                    + investReturn;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, returnValue);
            initYears++;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}

public class MakeInvestment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Investment otherClass = new Investment();
        double yA = otherClass.YEARS_DEFAULT;
        double mA = otherClass.AMOUNT_DEFAULT;

        while (inputAmount() == false) {
            inputAmount();
        }

        while (inputYears() == false) {
            inputYears();
        }

        otherClass.returnValue(yA, mA);

    }

    public static boolean inputAmount() {
        String amountAmount = "";

        amountAmount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Enter the amount to invest (9999).", "Investment Amount",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        if (amountAmount == null || amountAmount.length() == 0) {
            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(
                            null,
                            "Nothing entered - You must enter a number for amount invested.",
                            "Investment Amount Error",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < amountAmount.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(amountAmount.charAt(i))) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "You must enter a number for amount invested.",
                        "Investment Amount Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return false;
            }
        }

        double dblAmount = Double.parseDouble(amountAmount);

        return true;
    }

    public static boolean inputYears() {
        String yearAmount = "";

        yearAmount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Enter the number of years to invest.", "Investment Years",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        if (yearAmount == null || yearAmount.length() == 0) {
            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(
                            null,
                            "Nothing entered - You must enter a number for years to invest.",
                            "Investment Years Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < yearAmount.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(yearAmount.charAt(i))) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "You must enter a number of years to invest.",
                        "Investment Years Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return false;
            }
        }

        double dblYear = Double.parseDouble(yearAmount);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Too much code! Only post relevant parts of your code. Don't just dump all your code here and say "Fix this."

Comment: which part of your code goes wrong? I cannot see anywhere **two-parameters constructor** is invoked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is "forcing it to use the default constructor".  You're just only ever calling the default constructor

> ```
> Investment otherClass = new Investment()
> ```

To use the 2-argument constructor, pass in arguments

```
new Investment(2000.0D, 5.0D)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the lines:

```
public final static double AMOUNT_DEFAULT = 1000;
public Investment(double AMOUNT_DEFAULT, double YEARS_DEFAULT)
```

are the problem. You're declaring that AMOUNT_DEFAULT=1000 and declaring it as final. Therefore, it will always equal 1000. Try using a different variable name in your constructor.

Edit: I tested this quickly out of interest and it seems that the code will actually work as you intended. It would still be to your advantage to avoid that kind of variable naming however.